# Downloading image from optional URL in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I saw a lot of tutorials with a specific URL to download image but I have optional URL which would come from API and in image downloading function Xcode ask me to force-unwrap which i can't do.

```
cell.coverView?.image = downloader(StringURLFromAPI)
```

and in downloader function

```
func downloader(url: String?) -> UIImage {

    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: url))
    return UIImage(data: data)
}
```

TIA :)

Comment: First check that image URL is empty or not, then apply downloading of image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to make your `downloader` function return optional. It should return UIImage only if the NSURL and NSData objects were successfully created:

```
func downloader(url: String?) -> UIImage? {
    guard let url = url,
        let imageUrl = NSURL(string: url),
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl)
        else { return nil }

    return UIImage(data: data)
}
```

You can also check out this library for downloading images from remote urls:
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage